# Facet_wrap: Y scale from 0 to 1, based on variable plotted

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet-wrap

Is there a way to scale the y axis in facet wrap from 0 to 1, based on the variable plotted, in my case (see below) the gender? As if the `..count.. / max(..count..)` would be grouped on the `gender` variable. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Below is my current attempt

```
ex[c("var1","var2", "gender")] %>%
  gather(-gender, key="var", value = "value") %>% 
  ggplot(aes(value, fill = gender)) +  geom_histogram(aes(y=..count.. / max(..count..)), stat="count") + 
  facet_wrap(~var + gender, scales = "free_x", ncol= 2)  +
  ylab("% in each group")
```

Resulting in
[image]

Sample of the data:

```
structure(list(row = 1:100, var1 = c(" <25", " <25", " 25-50", 
" 25-50", " 50-75", " <25", " 25-50", " 25-50", " 25-50", " 25-50", 
" 50-75", " 25-50", " 25-50", " 25-50", " <25", " 25-50", " 25-50", 
" 25-50", " 25-50", " 25-50", " 25-50", " 25-50", " 25-50", " 25-50", 
">75", " 25-50", " 25-50", " <25", " <25", " 25-50", " 25-50", 
" 25-50", " 50-75", " 50-75", " 25-50", " 25-50", " 50-75", " 25-50", 
" 25-50", " <25", " 25-50", " 25-50", " 25-50", " 25-50", " <25", 
" 25-50", " 25-50", " 25-50", " 25-50", " 25-50", " 25-50", " 25-50", 
" 25-50", " 50-75", " 50-75", " <25", " 25-50", " <25", " 50-75", 
" <25", " <25", " <25", " 25-50", " <25", " <25", " 25-50", " 50-75", 
" 25-50", " 25-50", " 25-50", " 25-50", " 25-50", " <25", " 25-50", 
" <25", " 25-50", " 25-50", " 25-50", " 25-50", " 25-50", " <25", 
" 50-75", " 25-50", " 25-50", " 25-50", " 25-50", " 25-50", " 50-75", 
" 25-50", " <25", " 25-50", " 25-50", " <25", " 25-50", " <25", 
" <25", " 25-50", " 25-50", " <25", " <25"), var2 = c(0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L), gender = c("M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "F", "M", 
"M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", 
"M", "M", "F", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", 
"M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", 
"M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", 
"M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", 
"M", "M", "M", "M", "F", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", 
"F", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M"
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -100L))
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate what should add up to 100%, maybe you can give an expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge there is no out-of-the-box solution to tell `facet_wrap` to do the kind of normalization you are trying to achieve. Instead you have to do this manually.

There are (at least) two approaches to achieve this:

1. The easy approach would be to pre-compute the (normalized) counts and to make use of `geom_col`
2. The more elaborate approach would be to use e.g. `tapply` to compute the maximum counts by `gender`. For this approach I would recommend to switch to `geom_bar` instead of using `geom_histogram`.

Both approaches are shown below:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

ex[c("var1","var2", "gender")] %>%
  gather(-gender, key="var", value = "value") %>% 
  count(gender, var, value) %>% 
  group_by(gender) %>% 
  mutate(pct = n / max(n)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(value, pct, fill = gender)) +  
  geom_col() +
  facet_wrap(~var + gender, scales = "free_x", ncol= 2)  +
  ylab("% in each group")
```

[image]

```r
ex[c("var1","var2", "gender")] %>%
  gather(-gender, key="var", value = "value") %>% 
  ggplot(aes(value, fill = gender)) +  
  geom_bar(aes(y = ..count.. / tapply(..count.., ..fill.., function(x) max(x))[..fill..]), stat="count") + 
  facet_wrap(~var + gender, scales = "free_x", ncol= 2)  +
  ylab("% in each group")
```

[image]

Comment: Is there any way that the columns inside each category(for each variable) would sum to 1? Current solution I have is using `geom_bar(aes(y = ..count.. / tapply(..count.., ..fill.., function(x) sum(x))[..fill..]), stat="count")` for each variable separately + ylim(0,1) and then using grid.arrange, but I believe there should be a smoother solution? Many thanks

Comment: Hi @Randomcloud. Yep. grid.arrange is not needed. In general I would suggest that using my first approach via pre-computed values is easier to handle. There you can simply group_by var and gender. For the second approach you have to do `ggplot(aes(value, fill = gender, group = interaction(var, gender))) +  
  geom_bar(aes(y = ..count.. / tapply(..count.., ..group.., function(x) sum(x))[..group..]), stat="count")`. Here we first map `interaction(var, gender)` on `group` which can then be used in geom_bar or tapply to do the computation per variable/gender ...

Comment: ... in either case you still need the ylim(0, 1) to set the limits.